# boost asio and endian

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, endianness

I cant tell, does boost asio handle endian?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Asio does convert things like *port* into network order. The conversion functions are not exposed as part of the official interface and are hidden in the *detail* namespace instead (e.g. *boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::host_to_network_short*).

Answer (score 6):

boost::asio::socket_'s do not perform any byte order conversion.