# boost asio read / receive endianess

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, endianness

Reading data over a socket using boost asio tcp read functions or udp receive functions into a

```
 std::vector<char>,
```

does the data fill up the vector in network byte order or receiving-host byte order ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524453/boost-asio-and-endian

Answer (score 7):

You will receive the bytes in the same order they were sent.

"Endianness" only has a meaning when dealing with multi-byte numerical values - there are no such things when the message is regarded as a stream or packet of bytes as it is at the TCP/UDP transport layer.

If some of the bytes need to be interpreted as multi-byte values, then you'll need to know how they were encoded by the application layer. Neither TCP nor UDP sockets can help you with that.